# Error when running: yo keystone (Windows 10 x64, node 5.3.0, npm 3.3.12 )

Tags: node.js, keystonejs, yo

After installing generator-keystone:

```
$npm install -g generator-keystone
```

And yeoman generator:

```
$npm install -g yo
```

I'm running generator:

```
$yo keystone.
```

After answering the questions and completion of generator's work i receive the following error:

```
    97375 verbose stack Error: v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
97375 verbose stack Exit status 1
97375 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:232:16)
97375 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
97375 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
97375 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
97375 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
97375 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
97375 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
97375 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
97376 verbose pkgid v8-debug@0.4.6
97377 verbose cwd d:\Work\Samples\Web\keystone_test\test
97378 error Windows_NT 10.0.10240
97379 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
97380 error node v5.3.0
97381 error npm  v3.3.12
97382 error code ELIFECYCLE
97383 error v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
97383 error Exit status 1
97384 error Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
97384 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a 4.* version of Node?

I'd highly recommend using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) when developing node applications so you can easily switch between node versions.